# Is it possible to use android UI components in a Swing app?

Tags: java, swing, android

Is it possible to use android UI components in a Swing app?

For example, to use the Android API directly in my Swing project so I can use its UI components.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible at all, Android is not Java, Android code and libraries and frameworks and so, they all run on Dalvik VM, way different then Java Bytecode.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I got confused with this "Android is not Java". What do you mean? I thought to write Android apps you would use Java language. Not true? Anyway, I never did anything for android, so pardon me if I'm saying something stupid.

Comment: Although practically they are the same thing, in theory they aren't. I mean you write in Java and you use lots of Java SE libraries, but what gets executed is not Java bytecode (dex files, Dalvik VM, etc) and therefore it is not Java. Of course it's way more complicated then that, and this is all for performance and legal reasons (remember Oracle/Google issue regarding use of Java ME license, libs and so).

Answer (score 1):

No, that isn't possible. Those are two completely different beasts.